# How to extract values from an RDD based on the parameter passed

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created an key-value RDD , but i am not sure how to select the values from it.

```
val mapdf = merchantData_df.rdd.map(row => {
    val Merchant_Name = row.getString(0)
    val Display_Name = row.getString(1)
    val Store_ID_name = row.getString(2)
    val jsonString = s"{Display_Name: $Display_Name, Store_ID_name: $Store_ID_name}"
    (Merchant_Name, jsonString)
})

scala> mapdf.take(4).foreach(println)
(Amul,{Display_Name: Amul, Store_ID_name: null})
(Nestle,{Display_Name: Nestle, Store_ID_name: null})
(Ace,{Display_Name: Ace , Store_ID_name: null})
(Acme ,{Display_Name: Acme Fresh Market, Store_ID_name: Acme Markets})
```

Now suppose my input string to a function will be `Amul`, My expected output for `DisplayName is Amul` and another function for `StoreID to return NULL`.

How can i achieve it?

I don't want to use SparkSQL for this purpose

Comment: can you share your expected output and also the codes you have attempted?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have changed the requirements now. can you please help me?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Updated .

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, Updated the question again

Comment: it can be done through simple filter and select. did you try that?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Nope

Comment: @RameshMaharjan How to pass exact string to Filter?

Comment: just do `merchantData_df.select("Merchant_Name", "Store_ID_name").where(col("Merchant_Name") === "Fitch")`

Comment: When I am using it in a function, its giving the below error.
 ` def fetch_DisplayPanelName(paramText: String): String = {
merchantData_df.select("Merchant_Name:").where(col("Merchant_Name") === paramText)
}`

`console>:43: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: String
           merchantData_df.select("Merchant_Name").where(col("Merchant_Name") === paramText)`

Comment: the result will be a dataframe with two columns and not a string. you can do first()(1) to get the string

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Filter & select  is very slow on huge data.Any other way?

Comment: You should wait for others to answer then :)

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Can you please help me with a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given input dataframe as

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
|Merchant_Name    |Display_Name     |Store_ID_name|
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
|Fitch            |Fitch            |null         |
|Kids             |Kids             |null         |
|Ace Hardware     |Ace Hardware     |null         |
| Fresh Market    |Acme  Market     |Acme Markets |
|Adventure        | Island          |null         |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

You can write a function with string parameter as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def filterRowsWithKey(key: String) = df.filter(col("Merchant_Name") === key).select("Display_Name", "Store_ID_name")
```

And calling the function as

```
filterRowsWithKey("Fitch").show(false)
```

would give you

```
+------------+-------------+
|Display_Name|Store_ID_name|
+------------+-------------+
|Fitch       |null         |
+------------+-------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

If you want first row as string to be returned from the function then you can do

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def filterRowsWithKey(key: String) = df.filter(col("Merchant_Name") === key).select("Display_Name", "Store_ID_name").first().mkString(",")

println(filterRowsWithKey("Fitch"))
```

which should give you

```
Fitch,null
```

above function will throw exception if the key passed is not found so to be safe you can use following function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def filterRowsWithKey(key: String) = {
  val filteredDF = df.filter(col("Merchant_Name") === key).select("Display_Name", "Store_ID_name")
  if(filteredDF.count() > 0) filteredDF.first().mkString(",") else "key not found"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, But i have already did the same and the performance is really slow. That is why I am looking for  some other alternatives .

Comment: How can i make this into an UDF?

Comment: why do you want a udf?

Comment: Not any real reason behind the UDF, but i was just thinking, By the way, how can i get the output from the function filterRowsWithKey as a string instead of a DF?

Comment: I tried to return the value as string but getting the below error.
`scala> def get_PanelName(key: String) :String = { input_df.filter(col("Merchant_Name") === key).select("Display_Name") }
<console>:39: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: String
       def get_PanelName(key: String) :String = { input_df.filter(col("Merchant_Name") === key).select("Display_Name") }`

Comment: Ramesh, can it be possible to make an udf for the same?

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, But can it be possible to make a udf?

Comment: udf is for row by row manipulation and is not recommended when you have other alternatives. So give me valid reason to why you want udf function and I shall try to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171977/discussion-between-arjun-and-ramesh-maharjan).