# How do I return Multi-Column Key and Value pairs in Scala using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to transform the below RDD into Key Value Pairs, with each key having two values.
The first column should be the key and the second and third column should be the values. How can I use the Case class in scala to perform the transformation?

```
scala> input
res31: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[60] at rdd at <console>:35

scala> input.take(5).foreach(println)
[Ace,Ball,null]
[Kids,Kids,null]
[Hardware,Hardware,null]
[Market,Market,Markets]
[Adventure,Adventure,null]
```

Expected O/P:
I am expecting a key-value pairs much like a Python Dictionary. One key will hold multiple values , hence the values will be a tuple . Once we have the key value pairs, based on key i should be able to extract the values.

e.g

```
d = {key1: [val1, val2, val3....], key2: [valx, valy, valz, ...], ....}
```

`d[key1][0]` gives the first value of key1

Hope I am able to express my requirements clearly

Comment: can you share your expected output?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Updated my question

Comment: why don't you stick with dataframe?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I don't have any issue with Dataframes too . But I really don't to use any SparkSQL to do it. Think as 3 columns DF where 1st is key and next 2 are values, Provided the Key as an input string I need the 1st value or the 2nd value as per needed.

Comment: so you mean that if Ace is provided then you want Ball as 1st value and null as 2nd value?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: what if you have multiple Ace keys? i mean multiple rows with Ace as key?

Comment: The keys are unique. there will be no duplicates

Comment: @RameshMaharjan You can move this to chat

Comment: this is going to be the same conversation that we did for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563142/how-to-extract-values-from-an-rdd-based-on-the-parameter-passed whats the difference between these two questions?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, my requirements is the same in both question. I got the output using filter and select but that is really slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tuple2`. Assuming you want to have the output as:

```
(Ace, (Ball, null))
(Kids, (Kids, null))
..
(Adventure, (Adventure, null))
```

You can try the following:

```
val output = input.map(x => Tuple2(x.getString(0), (x.getString(1), x.getString(2))))
output.take(5).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Thanks, if I want to fetch the 1st value of the first key, what should i do?